# Show that sequence $a_n$ defined by $a_{n+1} := \frac{(a_n + b_n )}{2}$, $b_{n+1} := \sqrt{a_n b_n}$ is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_1 ≥ b_1 > 0$, and define $a_n$ and $b_n$ for all $n>
1$ as

$a_{n+1} := \frac{(a_n + b_n )}{2}$
and
$b_{n+1} := \sqrt{a_n b_n}$.

How can I show that the sequence $a_n$ is decreasing? I thought about using that $a_{n+1} - a_n < 0$, but it becomes rapidly unbearable.

Comment: Induction, directly.

Comment: $a_{n+1} - a_n < 0$ quickly becomes $a_n>b_n$. Induction is the way to go there.

Answer (score 2):

The case $a_1=b_1$ is trivial, so we assume $a_1>b_1$. Then by the AM-GM inequality we get $b_{n+1}<a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}}{2}<\frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}}{2}=a_{n+1}$.